# create a child for each file and pipe to parent

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

i'm trying to do a homework where i need to count the lines, words and characters of n files.

Each file in the list must be processed (counted) by a distinct process;
The hierarchical relationship between processes must be such that the i+1 process is created by the process i;

Example:

```
 PID    PPID   
child1 parent1 File1 l=2 w=5 c=20
child2 child1  File2 l=3 w=6 c=30

Total:               l=5 w=11 c=50
```

Each process sends the numbers to the parent with a pipe and the parent will sum them in 3 different variables. (totLines/totWords/totChars).

The problem is here, this 3 variables will reset to 0 in each fork() so my total will only show the last numbers sent to the pipe (Total: l=3 w=6 c=30) and i can't find a solution to this... I think the problem is on the break; of the parent, when i remove it the sum works but the program will repeat the prints 3/4 times.

Here's some of my code:

```
int send[3];
int get[3];
int fd[2];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        countFile(filename, send);
        printf("PID: %d - PPID: %d - %d %d %d\n", send[0], send[1], send[2]);
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], send, sizeof(send));
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    if (pid != 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], get, sizeof(get));
        totLines += get[0];
        totWords += get[1];
        totChars += get[2];
        close(fd[0]);
        break; // <--- removing this break makes the sum work but will print 
               //the total and the print in the child process multiple times
        
    }

    
}

int status;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    wait(&status);
}

if(i+1 == n){
    printf("Total: %d %d %d\n", totLines, totWords, totChars);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages, but it is more urgent that you learn how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.  You don't show the definitions of key variables like `get` and `send`.  It isn't clear (to me) how the code is used from `main()`, or if it is in fact an extract from `main()` that's shown.  You don't, but could, use asynchronous processes.

Comment: Given that the parent can only read from pipes that it creates, there should only be one pipe in use — all the children will use the same pipe. The parent process will read the pipe until EOF. Each child will (a) count the data for its file, (b) write the data to the parent, and (c) fork a child process to process the next file in the argument list. Step (a) must precede step (b), but the sequencing of (c) is not clearly defined — (c) could happen before (a) or between (a) and (b) or after (b).  The most sensible options are 'before (a)' and 'after (b)'.  Do you have to report file names?

Comment: thanks for helping, the code i wrote above is in main() and i use the function countFile to insert into the array int send[3] the lines, words and chars. I need to show the file names when i print the PID - PPID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207788/create-a-child-for-each-file-and-pipe-to-parent#comment124109650_70207788), given that the parent can only read from pipes it creates, the transfer of information from a child of a child of a child (as required by the "hierarchical relationship between processes must be such that the i+1 process is created by the process i" requirement) means that only one pipe is in use.

Further, the initial process has no sensible way of determining the PID of any process except its immediate child.  Therefore, more information must be passed back from the children.  The children can all use the same pipe as long as the data written per child is small enough and written in a single operation and the size can be determined.  Since the parental code must print the file name, PID and PPID, it seems reasonable to pass 6 data items back to the parent:

1. File number
2. PID
3. PPID
4. Line count
5. Word count
6. Byte count

These observations lead me to write this code — which substantially ignores what you have so far.  Note that I use my preferred error reporting code, which is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

There's one sneaky twist in the code — the use of the `random_children()` function to generate a random number of processes so that the PID values do not (in general) increment monotonically by 1.  You'd probably want to leave that out.

Note that the output format leaves the most variable bit — the file name — at the end of the line rather than embedding it in the middle.  It would be feasible to find the length of the longest name and format the file name after the two PID value and before the counts — consider it an exercise for the reader.

#### `pipe83.c`

```c
/* SO 7020-7788 */
/*
** Count the lines, words and characters of n files.
**
** - Each file in the list must be processed (counted) by a distinct
**   process;
** - The hierarchical relationship between processes must be such that
**   the i+1 process is created by the process i;
**
** Example:
**
**  PID    PPID
** child1 parent1 File1 l=2 w=5 c=20
** child2 child1  File2 l=3 w=6 c=30
**
** Total:               l=5 w=11 c=50
**
** Each process sends the numbers to the parent with a pipe and the
** parent will sum them in 3 different variables.
*/

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "stderr.h"

static void count_file(const char *file, int counts[3])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for reading: ", file);
    int lines =0;
    int words = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    int in_word = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        bytes++;
        if (c == '\n')
            lines++;
        if (isspace(c))
        {
            in_word = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!in_word)
                words++;
            in_word = 1;
        }
    }
    counts[0] = lines;
    counts[1] = words;
    counts[2] = bytes;
    fclose(fp);
}

static void random_children(void)
{
    srand(getpid());
    int n = rand() % 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to fork: ");
        if (pid == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

static void child_at_work(int fd, int argc, char **argv, int n)
{
    int data[6] = { n, getpid(), getppid(), 0, 0, 0 };
    random_children();
    count_file(argv[n], &data[3]);
    if (write(fd, data, sizeof(data)) != sizeof(data))
        err_syserr("failed to write data to pipe: ");
    if (n >= argc - 1)
        exit(0);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork: ");
    if (pid == 0)
        child_at_work(fd, argc, argv, n + 1);
    close(fd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc < 2)
        err_usage("file [...]");

    int p[2];
    if (pipe(p) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to create pipe: ");

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork: ");
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        err_setlogopts(ERR_LOG|ERR_MILLI);
        close(p[0]);
        child_at_work(p[1], argc, argv, 1);
        err_error("function child_at_work() returned unexpectedly\n");
    }

    close(p[1]);

    int data[6];
    /*
    ** 0 = file number
    ** 1 = PID
    ** 2 = PPID
    ** 3 = lines
    ** 4 = words
    ** 5 = bytes
    */

    int lines = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    printf("%5s  %5s\n", "PID", "PPID");
    while (read(p[0], data, sizeof(data)) == sizeof(data))
    {
        lines += data[3];
        words += data[4];
        bytes += data[5];
        printf("%5d  %5d  l=%5d w=%5d c=%5d  %s\n",
               data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], argv[data[0]]);
    }

    printf("%-14.14sl=%5d w=%5d c=%5d\n", "Total:", lines, words, bytes);
    close(p[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Running that on the C files in my 'Stack Overflow Questions' directory yields:

```
$ pipe83 *.c
  PID   PPID
56980  56979  l=   97 w=  251 c= 2206  checkeuid.c
56981  56980  l=   17 w=   55 c=  480  ex97.c
56989  56981  l=   36 w=  119 c=  752  fgets_delim67.c
56993  56989  l=   29 w=   61 c=  532  glob61.c
56995  56993  l=   35 w=  127 c=  993  lcs47.c
57001  56995  l=  195 w=  577 c= 4784  pipe13.c
57009  57001  l=   98 w=  322 c= 2906  pipe43.c
57013  57009  l=  143 w=  447 c= 3213  pipe83.c
57015  57013  l=   12 w=   36 c=  256  pragma83.c
57021  57015  l=   23 w=   66 c=  670  pth43.c
57029  57021  l=   41 w=  115 c=  908  rd83.c
57033  57029  l=  134 w=  460 c= 3461  revdigits.c
57035  57033  l=   34 w=  101 c=  593  rot71.c
57041  57035  l=   32 w=  115 c= 1076  scan13.c
57049  57041  l=   51 w=  131 c= 1033  scan67.c
57053  57049  l=   88 w=  297 c= 2946  sigcont17.c
57055  57053  l=   65 w=  139 c= 1732  sigcont31.c
57061  57055  l=   51 w=  148 c= 1384  sigcont43.c
57069  57061  l=  101 w=  194 c= 2383  so-6886-8740-1.c
57073  57069  l=   84 w=  257 c= 1938  test-strsep.c
Total:        l= 1366 w= 4018 c=34246
$ wc *.c
      97     251    2206 checkeuid.c
      17      55     480 ex97.c
      36     119     752 fgets_delim67.c
      29      61     532 glob61.c
      35     127     993 lcs47.c
     195     577    4784 pipe13.c
      98     322    2906 pipe43.c
     143     447    3213 pipe83.c
      12      36     256 pragma83.c
      23      66     670 pth43.c
      41     115     908 rd83.c
     134     460    3461 revdigits.c
      34     101     593 rot71.c
      32     115    1076 scan13.c
      51     131    1033 scan67.c
      88     297    2946 sigcont17.c
      65     139    1732 sigcont31.c
      51     148    1384 sigcont43.c
     101     194    2383 so-6886-8740-1.c
      84     257    1938 test-strsep.c
    1366    4018   34246 total
$
```